# bash script with lftp with redirected input

Tags: linux, networking, bash, ftp, lftp

I need lftp to connect to a list of hosts from a list file which are in IP address format. Then, if a ftp server is up, log that address (and if possible, device type, in this case routers) to a text file. For the servers that are up, I need it to connect without any credentials given and then use find to map the directories and files, then output that data to a file named after the server address. I tried to write a for loop with ftp but it was unsuccessful. I think lftp going to be the best option for what I need to do.

```
cat list6.txt | lftp | grep connected > livehosts.txt
```

Also:

```
for i [in LIST ]; do ftp; "echo welcome> *"; done > [IP Address].txt
```

At least help with the first part about redirecting the input to lftp would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with [Expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html).